# differentiable histogram in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How can one get a differentiable histogram function in tensorflow. I want to use the histogram of images to calculate a particular loss function. But the histogram function provided by tensorflow, tf.histogram_fixed_width() are not differentiable. How can I go about this ?

Comment: A differentiable loss can be naturally defined between two tensors of the same size with respect to the histograms of each (or more precisely, argsort).